# Can't create directory /var/www/html/var/generation/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/modelName/

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I've created custom module and it' created, the problem is when I'm trying to inject or get instance by object manager of the collection factory, I get this error

> Can't create directory
>   /var/www/html/var/generation/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/modelName/

I've given access permission to var/generation by this command `chmod -R 777 var/generation` but same error appears

Comment: do not throw around with 777 because that will solve your issue for now, but not the root cause!

Comment: Check your folder owner, `sudo chown www-data:www-data var/ -R`

Answer (score 0):

This is a configuration error.

Your webservers user might not be able to access directories before var/generation (e.g. var).

I would let the webserver run under the current user. this is acceptable for development-systems and resolves most permission errors.